# Ng serve or ng new does not work

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am getting this message on the terminal, saying that I'm not able to run the app. After enter `ng serve` to run the Angular application. Please see attached image:

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this?

Answer (score 9):

Simple solution here.

Try:

```
sudo apt purge ng-common ng-latin
```

And then, install angular with `sudo`:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: you should never use sudo for any npm commands. I learnt it the hard way.

Comment: @Pixsa can you please tell us the reason behind this issue?

Comment: @Susampath It was 2 years ago, I assume there was an corrupted angular installation.

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to setup an Angular 5 "Hello World" app in AWS EC2. After trying and dying in AWS Linux, I decided to use Ubuntu. During my install, the exact same thing kept happening... I would type `ng serve`, and it would throw me into Mg text editor.

After "fixing it" on one machine (just a ton of trial and error), i then later shelled into my instance from another machine only to have the same thing happen! I finally found a fix.

For each new machine from which you SSH (i use PuTTy), you may have to type the following at least one time...

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
source ~/.profile
```

On my second machine, i first checked my path (echo $PATH) and .npm was *not* showing up. Then after I entered those 4 lines, of course it did... and more importantly... NO MORE Mg Editor! woots. Now I can execute ng serve from a different laptop when needed.

Answer (score -2):

**1.**

Verify that you have the Angular Cli installed globally by running:
  `ng --version`. If that command doesn't work, install it by running: `npm install -g @angular/cli`

**2.**

Make sure your terminal is open in the directory in the same location as the location of your `angular-cli.json` file when you run the command.

**3.**

Make sure you type the right command. I don't really understand what's on the image you attached, but in the bottom of the terminal it says: *Mg: server*. Could it be that you just misspelled *ng* with *mg*?